# Using Knockout.js mapping plugin with an array in json

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am trying to set up an example in which a series of news items will be passed in using ajax in a json format. At the moment I am just using a function to simulate returned data.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8b4naL5/

```
           <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

                  <span data-bind="foreach: { data: newsItems, as: 'item' }" > 
                    <!-- <span data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }"> -->
                    <div class="news-item">
                       <span data-bind='text:item.title'></span>
                     </div>

                  </span>   
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function NewsItemsCall(){
        return {
            newsItemsFromCall: [
                {title:'First Title From call'},
                {title:'Second Title From call'}
            ]
        }
    }

    function NewsItem(newsItemsCall){
        var map = ko.mapping.fromJS(newsItemsCall);
        return map;
    }




    var viewModel = {
       newsItems:ko.observableArray([new NewsItem(new NewsItemsCall())])
    }


           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

The ko.toJSON displays the following:

```
{
  "newsItems": [
    {
      "newsItemsFromCall": [
        {
          "title": "First Title From call"
        },
        {
          "title": "Second Title From call"
        }
      ],
      "__ko_mapping__": {
        "ignore": [],
        "include": [
          "_destroy"
        ],
        "copy": [],
        "observe": [],
        "mappedProperties": {
          "newsItemsFromCall[0].title": true,
          "newsItemsFromCall[1].title": true,
          "newsItemsFromCall": true
        },
        "copiedProperties": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

At this point I am just trying to get it to work to display the data in the template. Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well the modification required could be approached from either the data side or the client side. At face value, your view isn't matched up to the data due to `newsItems` containing an array of `newItemsFromCall`. If the data is in the correct format, then just add another `foreach` binding.

- Modifying the data

  - `NewsItemsCall` could return an array instead of an object
  - be aware of the return of the `mapping` call depending on how you will be using that value elsewhere
- Modifying the UI

  ```
  <span data-bind="foreach: { data: newsItems, as: 'item' }" > 

    <div data-bind='foreach: item.newsItemsFromCall'>
      <span data-bind='text: title'></span>
    </div>

  </span>
  ```

[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/c8b4naL5/2/) with changes to the data structure. I also included an alternate approach that maps the `fromJS` call directly as a viewmodel.

---

Example of [mocking json calls](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/2ejstL1a/) in a fiddle.